# Need help to modify php script with switch-case

Tags: php, switch-statement

I need to modify this source php script code. When I modify with switch-case I've got an error no value for text1 when i give value text1

```
$query = "INSERT INTO mytable( text_name, text_image, text_detail ) VALUES ( :name,     :image, :detail ) ";
$query_params = array(
    ':name' => $_POST['text_name'],
    ':image' => $_POST['text_image'],
    ':detail' => $_POST['text_detail ']
);
```

To (something like) this

```
switch("text1" || "tex2" || "text3"){
            case "text1":
            $query = "INSERT INTO comments ( text_name, text_image, text1_detail)
    VALUES ( :name, :image, :detail) ";
      //Update query
    $query_params = array(
        ':name' => $_POST['text_name'],
    ':image' => $_POST['text_image'],
    ':detail' => $_POST['text1_detail']            
            );
            break;
            case "tex2":
            $query = "INSERT INTO comments ( text_name,text_image, text2_detail )
    VALUES ( :text_id, :image, :detail) ";
      //Update query
    $query_params = array(
        ':name' => $_POST['text_name'],
        ':image' => $_POST['text_image'],
        ':detail' => $_POST['text2_detail ']
            );
            break;
            case "text3":
            $query = "INSERT INTO comments ( text_name, text_image, text3_detail)
    VALUES ( :text, :image, :detail) ";
      //Update query
    $query_params = array(
        ':name' => $_POST['text_name'],
    ':image' => $_POST['text_image'],
    ':detail' => $_POST['text3_detail'],           
            );
            break;
            default: echo "Something is wrong fuckingshit!! Give me at least text1 or text2 or text3 !!!";
    }
```

But I get error no value for text1 when i give there text1, what is wrong? any suggestions?

Comment: When all else fails, read the manual http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: `switch("text1" || "tex2" || "text3")` becomes `switch(1)` essentially, why it won't match strings hencefurther. Also consider a username more according to customs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `switch` statement accepts a variable, and evaluates it against every value in the `case`s:

```
switch ($yourVariable) {
    case "text1": # Equivilent to if ($yourVariable == "text1")
        # do stuff
        break;
    case "text2":
        # do different stuff
        break;
    case "text3":
        # etc.
        break;
}
```

Comment: thanks I saw this example in php manual site, but I didn't understand, now I see. But i don't have varuable, this is like random. I got this from android

Comment: in android I have 3 button if user click first button in php I gave text1, second text2 and so on. How to fix this problem?